# In Tensorflow, what does tf.GradientTape.gradients do when its "target" attribute is a multi-dimensional tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In my model, I'm using tf.keras.losses.MSE to calculate the **mean squared error** of my **BATCH_SIZE x 256 x 256 x 3** output and my **BATCH_SIZE x 256 x 256 x 3** input.

The **output** of this function appears to be **(None,256,256)**.

I then use tf.GradientTape.gradients, with the MSE **output** as the "**target**" attribute. In the documentation, it says that this attribute can be a tensor.

My understanding is that **loss is a scalar number** which is differentiated against each of the weights during backpropagation.

Therefore, my question is: **What happens when a multi-dimensional tensor is passed into the gradients function? Is the sum of all elements in the tensor simple calculated?**

I ask this because my model is not training at the moment, with loss reading at 1.0 at every epoch. My assumption is that I am not calculating the gradients correctly, as all my gradients are reading as 0.0 for each weight.

Comment: You need to reduce the per pixel loss to a scalar. Use `tf.math.reduce_mean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable([3.0, 2.0])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
print(dy_dx)
print(y)

Result: 
tf.Tensor([6. 4.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([9. 4.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

As described in the figure above, `tf.GradientTape.gradient` simply calculates the gradient dy/dx. In your case with multiple variables, tf seems to calculate the derivative of the corresponding tensor instead of automatically summing them.

Comment: then apply gradients what does with the multidim tensor ?

Comment: @DanielWiczew If you are asking what [`apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#apply_gradients) does, this function defined in the optimizer receives a tuple of the gradients and variables and then performs some kind of operation to modify the variables(e.g. Adam, SGD).